SQL Oracle - Looking for query to check if record exists (Y/N)
I have two tables (Items and Options)
I need a query that will pull all items and make a validation (Y/N) against the options for that item:
Here are the tables
Items



id
name




1
Table


2
Chair


3
Box


4
Fridge


5
Window



Options
|



id
item
color




1
Table
Green


2
Table
Blue


3
Chair
Black


4
Chair
Red


5
Box
Yellow


6
Fridge
White


7
Fridge
Purple


8
Window
Gray


9
Window
Red



Here is the expected query result
Query Result



item
is red




Table
N


Chair
Y


Box
N


Fridge
N


Window
Y




"I need" is no question. Please remove images and url's and rather provide sample input data and expected result as tables with text. Read here how to do that. Then please add your attempt to solve the problem and explain what exactly you want to know.

It's also considered polite on stackoverflow, to show what you have tried so far to achieve your goal.

You can try something like this to check if the value is red or not:
SELECT item.Item_ID AS Item_ID,
    CASE 
        WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Options optns WHERE optns.Item_ID = item.Item_ID AND optns.Color = 'Red') THEN RPAD('Y', 6)
        ELSE RPAD('N', 6)
    END AS "is Red" FROM Items item;


You can use a LEFT OUTER JOIN:
SELECT i.name,
       CASE o.color WHEN 'Red' THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END AS is_red
FROM   items i
       LEFT OUTER JOIN options o
       ON i.name = o.item AND o.color = 'Red'

Which, for the sample data:
CREATE TABLE Items (name) AS
SELECT 'Table'  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Chair'  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Box'    FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Fridge' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Window' FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE Options (item, color) AS
SELECT 'Table',  'Green'  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Table',  'Blue'   FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Chair',  'Black'  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Chair',  'Red'    FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Box',    'Yellow' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Fridge', 'White'  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Fridge', 'Purple' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Window', 'Gray'   FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Window', 'Red'    FROM DUAL;

Outputs:



NAME
IS_RED




Chair
Y


Window
Y


Fridge
N


Table
N


Box
N



fiddle

just
SELECT a.item, MAX(CASE WHEN a.color = 'Red' THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END) AS 'is red'
FROM Options AS a
GROUP BY a.item;

if need filtering exists items table
SELECT a.item, a.is_red AS "is red"
FROM 
(
    SELECT a.item, MAX(CASE WHEN a.color = 'Red' THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END) AS is_red
    FROM Options AS a
    GROUP BY a.item
) AS a 
INNER JOIN Items AS b ON b.name = a.item;

or using exists or other things
